# Is equality proof valid if terms are moved across equality?

Tags: probability

> For any two events A and B with $Pr(B) > 0$, prove that $Pr(A^c|B) = 1− Pr(A|B)$.

Is there a valid way to finish a proof if a step moves a term across the equality as follows?

Show:

$Pr(A^c|B) = 1− Pr(A|B)$

$Pr(A^c|B) + Pr(A|B) = 1 - Pr(A|B) + Pr(A|B)$

$1 = (Pr(A\cap B) + Pr(A^C \cap B))/Pr(B) $

$= Pr(B \cap (A \cup A^C)) / P(B) $

$= Pr(B)/Pr(B) = 1$

Therefore
 $Pr(A^c|B) + Pr(A|B) = 1$, and $Pr(A^c|B) = 1− Pr(A|B)$

Comment: If you start at $1=P(B)/P(B)$ and work backwards, it might be easier to see that you've already proved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just drop the first line after "Suppose"?  Everything after that is correct and proves the proposition.  Good job!